Prevent update of SwiftUI Chart on non-changed data
I have a SwiftUI Chart, which takes a collection of structs as its data. These structs have an id which is stable. The collection itself is also stable. There is also another value provided to the view (via a @Binding). This value does change, based on activities in the parent view.
The Chart rerenders its contents every time the @Binding 'otherValue' changes. Even though the  data of the collection provided to the Chart does not change. This makes the UI very sluggish because the collection contains about a 1000 items. The structs have an id and implement Equatable, so SwiftUI should be able to see that they are the same. Am I misunderstanding SwiftUIs behavior?
I've included below semi-pseudocode to illustrate the issue.
    struct ChartData : Equatable {
       id: UUID
       key: Double
       value: Double
    }
    
    struct ChartView: View {
        var chartData: [ChartData]
        @Binding var otherValue: Int

        var body: some View {
            Chart(chartData, id: \.id) {
                LineMark(x: .value("x", $0.key),
                         y: .value("y", $0.value))
        }
    }


Your pseudo code isn't very meaningful, how is otherValue used in the view?

You are correct that SwiftUI will compare Equatable things and do not update the view if they are the same.
However, this comparison is done on a body-by-body basis. SwiftUI is not smart enough to see that specifically the Chart does not depend on otherValue. All it sees is that you access both otherValue and chartData in ChartView.body, therefore it should call ChartView.body whenever any of those changes. SwiftUI treats each body as a whole.
So to stop SwiftUI from updating the chart when otherValue changes, you should extract the Chart-related code into a new body - another View.
struct ChartView: View {
    let chartData: [ChartData]
    @Binding var otherValue: Int

    var body: some View {
        TheActualChart(chartData: chartData)
        SomeOtherViewThatUsesOtherValue(otherValue)
    }
}

struct TheActualChart: View {
    let chartData: [ChartData]

    var body: some View {
        Chart(chartData, id: \.id) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}

Now when otherValue changes, ChartView.body will still be called, but TheActualChart.body won't be called.

Change
@Binding var otherValue: Int

to
let otherValue: Int

@Binding var is when you need read/write, if you only need read it's let, which appears to be your case in this child View. body is called when the value changes in both cases. @Binding is a simply group of 2 get/set closures which are not Equatable like an Int is, thus body is called every time a View with @Binding is re-init. Although depending on where the Binding came from there can be optimisations on that.
